# Sql server Index Size is 100 GB

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

**my problem is server CPU and ram goes to 100%** .

Is any problem in my indexing i had checked the index size by googling that the size is nearly 100 GB (94582.4 MB). what is the issue and its problem to server and SQL performance.

Comment: `what is the issue and its problem to server and SQL performance` a million dollar question isn't it? :) if we all could get answers for this question from online platforms no one will be hiring SQL Server consultants or even DBAs :) .

Comment: [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/)

Comment: @RemusRusanu thank u for your suggestion